# how to repeat a script in another code with another input data

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, popen, repeat

I am newbie in python  I wrote a code that in this I load a txt file and I get my result in another txt file, and I want to repeat this code for other txt files that I have all of them in same folder. I want to load almost 300 txt files and do this, but I don't know how do that. thanks

```
dat = np.loadtxt('test1.txt')
x = dat[:, 0]
y = dat[:, 2]
peak = LorentzianModel()
constant = ConstantModel()
pars = peak.guess(y, x=x)
pars.update( constant.make_params())
pars['c'].set(1.04066)
mod = peak + constant
out=mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
comps = out.eval_components(x=x)
writer = (out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
path = '/Users/dellcity/Desktop/'
filename = 'output.txt'
with open(path + filename, 'wt') as f:
    f.write(writer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define a function that gets the filename as a parameter and in the main part of your programm create a loop in which you find all files which you want to load and then call the function, e.g.:

```
import os

def myFunction(filename):
    dat = np.loadtxt(filename)
    x = dat[:, 0]
    y = dat[:, 2]
    peak = LorentzianModel()
    constant = ConstantModel()
    pars = peak.guess(y, x=x) 
    pars.update( constant.make_params())
    pars['c'].set(1.04066)
    mod = peak + constant
    out=mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
    comps = out.eval_components(x=x)
    writer = (out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
    path = '/Users/dellcity/Desktop/'
    filename = 'output.txt'
    # open in mode a = append
    with open(path + filename, 'at') as f:
       f.write(writer)    

# the parameter of os.listdir is the path to your file, 
# change to the path of your data files
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        myFunction(filename)
```